# Error in CardView

Tags: android

I want to create CardView layout but I getting this type of error.....
also give me suggestion  if any library or any jar file add in to project ..
code or error is here....
error

```
03-08 00:10:05.836: E/AndroidRuntime(3916): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 00:10:05.836: E/AndroidRuntime(3916): Process: com.test.cardview, PID: 3916
03-08 00:10:05.836: E/AndroidRuntime(3916): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test.cardview/com.test.cardview.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class android.support.v7.widget.CardView
```

xml file..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#C92A2A">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/sample_text_header" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/info_image"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription="@string/sample_text_image"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/info_text_footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingTop="80dp"
            android:text="@string/sample_text_footer" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You are declaring the same namespace twice.  Remove the cardview namespace and just use android:

Comment: can u give me example

Comment: plz correction on this code

Answer (score 0):

Remove the below in your CardView as its already declared.

```
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

It should just be:

```
.............................
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#C92A2A">
.................
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added the [appcompact library](https://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html) for cardview

Comment: ya i already add appcompact library...also recyclerview is working but cardview not working